# Using SQL SMS, how do I combine multiple rows into one row, but maintain all the column data?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, merge, rows

The data I am working with is currently in the form of:

```
 ID     Sex     Treatment    FillDate     
 1      M       ziprosidone  10/01/98     
 1      M       ziprosidone  10/15/98
 1      M       ziprosidone  10/29/98
 1      M       ambien       01/07/99
 1      M       ambien       01/14/99
 2      F       telaprevir   03/08/92
 2      F       telaprevir   03/20/92
 2      F       telaprevir   04/01/92
```

And I would like to write SQL code to get the data in the form of:

```
 ID     Sex     DrugFill1     FillDate1_1     FillDate1_2     FillDate1_3    DrugFill2     FillDate2_1     FillDate2_2     FillDate2_3     
 1      M       ziprosidone   10/01/98        10/15/98        10/29/98       ambien        01/07/99        01/14/99        null
 2      F       telaprevir    03/08/92        03/20/92        04/01/92       null          null            null            null
```

Also I would like to note that I have over 10,000 IDs, each with varying amounts of drugs and corresponding fill dates. I would like to return null values for those columns that do not have data to fill in. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If doing this within the RDBMS then this is called a pivot. But it's better practice to handle issues of data display in application level code, e.g. a simple PHP loop if that's available.

Comment: @Justin, Have you checked my answer? Please vot up and/or mark as accepted if helpful... Thx

Comment: @Shnugo I apologize for the delay, I was traveling. Thank you for the detailed response, your code and logic seem to be very close to what I am looking for. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Shnugo question, in the first `SELECT DISTINCT ID, Sex FROM @tbl` is it necessary to have the Sex variable in there? I only ask because suppose I also have a Race column in addition to Sex, do i need to include it in that first `SELECT DISTINCT` statement as well? Thanks!

Comment: @Justin, hi, yes, the first statement inlcudes the data which does not change with the Treatment. Btw: Better so set such a comment below the answer it belongs to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this solution is very close to what you need. If you need further help to set your drugs in one row "side by side", just tell me. Actually I  would not do this... Paste this into an empty query window and execute. Adapt to your needs...

EDIT: Changed this to your new drug names.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT,Sex VARCHAR(1),Treatment VARCHAR(30),FillDate DATETIME);

INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,'M','ziprosidone',{ts'1998-01-01 00:00:00'})     
,(1,'M','ziprosidone',{ts'1998-10-15 00:00:00'})
,(1,'M','ziprosidone',{ts'1998-10-29 00:00:00'})
,(1,'M','ambien',{ts'1999-01-07 00:00:00'})
,(1,'M','ambien',{ts'1999-01-14 00:00:00'})
,(2,'F','telaprevir',{ts'1992-03-08 00:00:00'})
,(2,'F','telaprevir',{ts'1992-03-02 00:00:00'})
,(2,'F','telaprevir',{ts'1992-04-01 00:00:00'});

WITH DistinctIDs AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ID,Sex FROM @tbl
)
,DistinctDrugs AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT DistinctIDs.ID
                   ,DistinctIDs.Sex
                   ,tbl.Treatment
                   ,'Drug_' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tbl.ID,tbl.Treatment ORDER BY tbl.Treatment) AS VARCHAR(100)) AS PivotColumnName 
    FROM DistinctIDs
        INNER JOIN @tbl AS tbl ON DistinctIDs.ID=tbl.ID
)
SELECT p.ID 
      ,p.Sex
      ,p.Treatment
      ,CAST(p.Drug_1 AS XML).value('/root[1]/item[1]/FillDate[1]','datetime') AS Date_1
      ,CAST(p.Drug_1 AS XML).value('/root[1]/item[2]/FillDate[1]','datetime') AS Date_2
      ,CAST(p.Drug_1 AS XML).value('/root[1]/item[3]/FillDate[1]','datetime') AS Date_3
FROM
(
    SELECT DistinctDrugs.*
          ,SubRows.XMLContent
    FROM DistinctDrugs
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT tbl.FillDate
        FROM @tbl  AS tbl
        WHERE tbl.ID=DistinctDrugs.ID AND tbl.Treatment=DistinctDrugs.Treatment
        FOR XML PATH('item'),ROOT('root')
    ) AS SubRows(XMLContent)
) AS DataToPivot
PIVOT
(
    MIN(XMLContent) FOR PivotColumnName IN(Drug_1,Drug_2,Drug_3 /*as many as needed*/)
) AS p
```

Comment: hi there, thanks for the comment tip.. I ran the code and it seems to be creating two rows for ID=1. In other words there is one row for ID=1 with Drug1 and its filldates, and then a second row for ID=1 with Drug2 and its filldates..I would like to have one unique row per ID with all of the corresponding drugs and filldates for that ID on that row..Thanks for all your help thus far!

Comment: @Justin, this is exactly what I wrote in my answer's header ;-) I'll help you tomorrow, to late now ;-)

Comment: whoops, I just noticed that you wrote precisely that! :P fantastic, I really do appreciate it. Goodnight.

Comment: @Justin, If you appreciate that, It would be nice, to set back the accepted check ;-)

Comment: done :) I apologize, I didn't know the protocol on that. Also, you will notice I edited my post from Drug1, Drug2, etc. to the actual drug names, as I realize when I ran the code this is important, and my data doesn't have it as "drug1" but rather the actual drug name. Cheers

Comment: @Justin, I edited my post. Hope this is what you need... I would not set the drugs side by side, as there count may vary and you'll have to create a result table with all columns you might expect for the maximum count. Additionally pivoting with more than one column is quite tricky and you'll not get your column captions easily...

Comment: @Justin, about "the protocol"... Just for your information: People who come here to answer are hungry for reputation points. One up vote (the triangle) brings 10 points, one accepted answer (the check below) 15 points. Taking away the accepted check reduces my rep count. So: accpeting and upvoting is a way to say thank you and makes the answerer happy ;-)